# Android- developing applications, do you need license to buy?

Tags: android

Do you need any license to buy for developing android applications?

Answer (score 2):

Developing is free (apart from your time / tools etc).

Publishing will require you to have a developers account, which I believe is around $25.

Answer (score 0):

Go there to [create your Google Developers Account](https://market.android.com/publish). It will cost you 25$ to be able to publish your softwares on the Android Market.

Comment: The 25$ are just for the subscription and you pay it once. Google takes 30% of the revenues of paid apps for "carriers and billing settlement fees", nothing for the free apps.